# kafka producer throw EOFException during running

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka 0.8.2.1 and the New Producer API. 
The server is setup as single node in local network.
The problem is that the producer throws an `EOFException` after running for a while (15 minutes last time I checked), but it doesn't seem to matter because my producer continues to work after this.

The way I initialize the producer:

```
Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
configs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.1.101:9092");
configs.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
configs.put(ProducerConfig.BLOCK_ON_BUFFER_FULL_CONFIG, "false");
configs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
configs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
this.producer = new KafkaProducer<>(configs);
```

And the exception I got:

```
WARN  [2015-06-17 02:07:28,896] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector: Error in I/O with /192.168.1.101
! java.io.EOFException: null
! at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
! at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:248) ~[kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Even though my code still works with this, I'd like to know why and how to prevent it.

Comment: I have the same issue now, have you figured it out already? Look like there is an official issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2078

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change "connections.max.idle.ms"? Its default is 15 minutes. If you see this error every 15 minutes try to reduce this timeout.

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3205
Suggesting increase connections.max.idle.ms